# How to Update a collection without defining the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I've to update a collection in my DB. I don't want to define a schema and want to refer an existing collection as we do in MongoDB. Is there a way to do the same?

Comment: Just use the Python client for MongoDB? http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: @aadarshsg he's using node.js

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define a schema

Update example, taken from the node.js MongoDB driver documentation: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/Readme.md

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    db.collection('user').update({_id: '507f191e810c19729de860ea'}, {$set: {firstName: 'John'}}, {w:1}, function(err) {
      if (err) console.warn(err.message);
      else console.log('successfully updated');
    });
  });
```

This will find the document in the `user` collection, with `_id` of 507f191e810c19729de860ea and set it's `firstName` property to 'John'

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a schemaless database and there isn't any predefined schema for your collections.

just do the normal insert or update and add new fields to the document.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking to update collection using mongoose. So figured it out how to update it without defining schema.
Schema needs to be passed blank and another parameter strict should be passed as false.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ }, {strict : false});
```